# Creating epoll()able objects

Tags: python, linux, select, epoll

Is it possible to create an object that will support `epoll()`?

I assume the `epoll_*` system calls depending on a compatible system fd makes it difficult, if not impossible, to create an object with a compatible 'pseudo fd'- but thought I'd see if I was wrong. ( it happens :p )

Comment: I think this requires writing a device driver to which you open a fd that can be `epoll`ed.

Comment: @Linuxios Thats my assumption as well- I wouldn't think you could have a single userspace process waiting for a `poll()` to return AND triggering notifications from within said python object... But I just wanted to be sure before I completely wrote off the idea. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the object write to one side of a `pipe(2)`, and pass the other end to `epoll.register()`. Obviously the object can't run in the same thread and at the same time as `epoll.poll()`. But that still leaves other valid usescases.